# Who were the 12 countries that voted against condemning Russia at the World Health Assembly yesterday?

Tags: who

The World Health Assembly yesterday gathered to vote on a resolution to condemn Russia's aggression in Ukraine and also how to best respond to the health crisis there too.

There were 53 abstentions and also 12 countries who voted against.

I tried searching on their site [here](https://www.who.int/news/item/26-05-2022-seventy-fifth-world-health-assembly---daily-update--26-may-2022), however there was no immediate publication of the breakdown of the results. I was wondering where may I find these results?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

On the right-hand section of the [75th World Health Assembly webpage](https://www.who.int/about/governance/world-health-assembly/seventy-fifth-world-health-assembly), we find that [Journal No. 6, 27 May 2022](https://apps.who.int/gb/Journal/e/WHA75/JRN-A75-6_en.html) contains a breakdown of the votes in Item 16 (Pillar 2) *continued*.

> The Chair opened item 16.3 and invited the Committee to consider the draft resolution contained in document A75/A/CONF./6 Health emergency in Ukraine and refugee receiving and hosting countries, stemming from the Russian Federation’s aggression.
>
> Two delegations took the floor to introduce their respective draft resolutions.
>
> In accordance with Rule 74 of the Rules of Procedure, a roll-call vote was taken. The Chair drew a letter in order to identify the first country to vote which was “J”. The vote resulted in 88 votes in favour to 12 votes against, with 53 abstentions and 30 Member States absent, as follows:
>
> Votes in favour: [...]
>
> **Votes against: Algeria, Belarus, Burundi, China, Cuba, Democratic People's Republic of Korea, Eritrea, Lao People's Democratic Republic, Mali, Nicaragua, Russian Federation, and Syrian Arab Republic.**
>
> Abstentions: Angola, Armenia, Bahrain, Bangladesh, Bhutan, Bolivia (Plurinational State of), Botswana, Brazil, Brunei Darussalam, Cameroon, Dominica, Egypt, El Salvador, Eswatini, Ethiopia, India, Iran (Islamic Republic of), Iraq, Jordan, Kazakhstan, Kenya, Kuwait, Kyrgyzstan, Lebanon, Madagascar, Malaysia, Maldives, Mauritania, Mongolia, Mozambique, Namibia, Niger, Nigeria, Oman, Pakistan, Philippines, Qatar, Saint Vincent and the Grenadines, Sao Tome and Principe, Saudi Arabia, Senegal, South Africa, Sri Lanka, Sudan, Togo, Tunisia, Uganda, United Arab Emirates, United Republic of Tanzania, Uzbekistan, Viet Nam, Zambia and Zimbabwe.
>
> Absent: Antigua and Barbuda, Azerbaijan, Benin, Burkina Faso, Central African Republic, Congo, Cook Islands, Côte d'Ivoire, Democratic Republic of the Congo, Djibouti, Guinea, Guinea-Bissau, Guyana, Hungary, Kiribati, Lesotho, Liberia, Libya, Malawi, Morocco, Nauru, Palau, Saint Kitts and Nevis, Saint Lucia, Samoa, Serbia, Sierra Leone, Tajikistan, Tonga, and Turkmenistan.